# How do i fix my Android Studio "Variant cannot be signed" error?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I just fetched a git repo using the cookiecutter extension for python. Downloading was no problem, but when I try to run the app, it shows me an error:

Error: The apk for your currently selected variant cannot be signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (development-debug).

[image: ERROR as an image]

[image: Shows a red X symbol]

I found no resolution to the problem online, so please help me!

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using. And if publicly available, what's the link to this git repo?

Comment: AS 11.0.11
Here you go: https://github.com/allaboutapps/A3AndroidTemplate

Comment: Thanks I actually fixed it myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is future you!

Fixing this problem is easy. Go to File -> Project Structure -> Build Variants -> app -> debug -> Signing Config.

Then u have to change it to "$signingConfigs.debug"

[image]